# AngularJS / Firebase : $scope data not rendering in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'd like to display some data stored in a Firebase database. I've got no problem getting the data into the scope but it isn't displayed to the user.

```
    var ref = new Firebase('https://URL.firebaseio.com/users');

    $scope.users = [];

    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var dataUser = childSnapshot.val()
            dataUser.id = childSnapshot.key()
            $scope.users.push(dataUser);
        });
    });
```

The ng-inspector Chrome extension does confirm that the data is loaded into the scope.

[image]

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using $scope.$apply; to have angularjs update the digest loop

Comment: Try if (!$scope.$$phase && !$scope.$root.$$phase) {
                        $scope.$digest();
                    } after forEach loop

Comment: @inspired's answer will work. An alternative is to use AngularFire, which internally calls `$timeout()` whenever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services like `$http` and `$setTimeout` automatically call `$apply()` method for you when making asynchronous changes to the `$scope`so that the DOM will be updated. You will need to call `$scope.$apply();` to trigger the `$digest` loop.

You could do:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://URL.firebaseio.com/users');

$scope.users = [];

ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var dataUser = childSnapshot.val()
        dataUser.id = childSnapshot.key()
        $scope.users.push(dataUser);
    });
    $scope.$apply(); //let angular know to trigger $digest loop to update the DOM.
});
```